# Django self.request not filtering though query

Tags: python, html, django, search

I am trying to achive some basic search in my search template, but when I search, it works in the URL, but doesn't change any of the posts in the template.

Views:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "public/search.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['queryset'] = Post.objects.filter(live=True)
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

    def SearchListView(request):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(title_icontains=query)
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to set things up as the tutorial I was watching was not using class based views.

HTML:

```
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="banner-search-main mb-5">
        <form method='GET' action=''>
            <p class="text-muted">Keywords:</p>
            <input type="text" name='q' class="homebanner-search" placeholder="Enter your keywords" value='{{ request.get.q }}'>
            <input type="submit" value="search">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="detail-container">
        {% for post in queryset %}
            <div class="col-sm card-container">
                <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}">
                    <div class="main-card">
                        <div class="main-card-img">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/270x150" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-card-body">
                            <p class="featured-category category-{{ post.category.colorcode }}">{{ post.category }}</p>
                            <p class="featured-title">{{ post.title }}</p>
                            <div class="featured-authcat">
                                <p class="featured-author mr-3"><i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>{{ post.author|title }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="featured-subtitle">{{ post.sub_description|truncatewords:25 }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

EXAMPLE:
[image]

Comment: have you checked if you really get query in view? Just print it to see if it is None or sport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your ListView with get_queryset method

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "public/search.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(live=True)
       query = self.request.GET.get("q")
       if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=query)
       return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(SearchListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['queryset'] = self.get_queryset()
       context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
       return context
```

Comment: Seem to be getting a 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' error

Comment: Ah yes that fixed it... but getting a 'Cannot resolve keyword 'title_icontains' into field.' which is odd...

Comment: do you have the field title in your Post model ?   maybe typo its  title__icontains

Answer (score 0):

You forgot self as the first parameter in your searchListView

```
def SearchListView(self, request):
    query = self.request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(title_icontains=query)
```

and for a better pythonic pep-8 style,The function name should be `search_list_view`.

check pep-8 for [Method Names and Instance Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id47)

```
def search_list_view:
    ....
```

and for what you are trying to accomplish it's better override `get_queryset` from the ListView.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SearchListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['queryset'] = self.get_queryset()
    context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(SearchListView, self).get_queryset().filter(live=True)
    query = self.request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=query)
    return queryset
```

Comment: This still didn't work. I think its something to do with the queryset = queryset.filter part? I don't think I am doing that part correctly.

Comment: I updated the answer, as it's better to use get_queryset.

Comment: Updated for get_context_data, and adding live=True in the queryset filter.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you created a random function in your class which does not override anything. What you are trying to do is override `get_queryset()`.

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "public/search.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['queryset'] = self.get_queryset()
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(live=True)
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=query)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest visiting [this](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) to view the infrastructure of class-based views.

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "public/search.html"
    success_url ='where you want to redirect'


    def get_queryset(self): # method that returns the queryset is `get_queryset`
       query = self.request.GET.get("q")
       if query:
        queryset = self.model.objects.filter(title__icontains=query) # double underscore not single
       return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(SearchListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['queryset'] = self.get_queryset()
       context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
       return context
```